# Mysql Order By issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having this issue with my MYSQL select statement

```
$forumresult = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM forumentry 
                               WHERE category = '".$category."' 
                               ORDER BY postdate DESC");

$forumresult->execute();
```

it does the Select and WHERE parts fine but it does not perform the Order by part

Thanks in advance any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see where you're echoing that. You're just preparing/executing. Nor do we know what the values are and the schema.

Comment: if you logged off of Stack, don't expect a magic solution to appear. You didn't post enough code or the schema for this.  -1 for the question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQL, an MCVE includes the databse sructure and content in an esasily reuseable form, e.g. for SQLite a `.dump` of a toy database.  
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your order query should be like that:

```
$forumresult = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM forumentry WHERE category = '".$category."' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE('postdate','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') DESC"); 

$forumresult->execute();
```

Edit your date type on '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'

Comment: Thanks for the help